# Floating action button: how to change the splash color and highlight color like in a RaisedButton?

Tags: dart, flutter, floating-action-button

I see that the splash and highlight colors that the FAB takes are connected to argument color in the MaterialApp widget. is there a way to override those colors? I found only foreground color and background colors and those are not what I want. Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you check the source code of `FloatingActionButton` the splash color is tied to the Theme of the app, so you can change the theme only for the button, like this:

```dart
Theme(
  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(highlightColor: Colors.yellow),
  child: FloatingActionButton(
    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Text("hello world"),
 ),
)
```

Comment: I think you could create a Stateless widget with that theme.

Comment: Wow thank you. That is great. Didn't even think I could make another Theme Widget only for the button. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

While the current answer works for setting the highlight color of a single `FloatingActionButton`, you could also define the splash color and highlight color globally. The splash color can be defined directly for the `FloatingActionButton`, though, the highlight color comes from your theme.

```dart
final theme = ThemeData(
  highlightColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.25),
  ...,
  floatingActionButtonTheme: FloatingActionButtonThemeData(
    splashColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.25),
    ...,
  ),
);
```

Then, simply add your theme to your `MaterialApp` like this

```dart
  MaterialApp(
    theme: theme,
    ...,
  )
```